# hashmap full and new element refer to bucket of some old hascode

Tags: java, hashmap, bucket

i know as the hashmap is full it will rehash and increase the hashmap size,following are my que:
1.If the size of hashmap is full and what if the new element to be added has the hashcode that refrences bucket from the same hashmap..will the hashing  done?
2.If hashing is done where will the new element stored.

Comment: What does a hash map being full mean? Each bucket has some dynamic data structure meaning that as elements are added the map becomes more “loaded” but never “full” (unless your app runs out of memory, but I guess that isn’t the case). Once the load crosses some value (number of elements divided by number of bucket is greater than some number), rehashing takes place so that all elements are “rehashed”, then the new element can be added (this happens without users having to do anything but does result in some operations being slower)

Comment: Hashmap or any java collection rebuilds itself to double the capacity when it's full. I think 10 is default size. So, it should rehash everything. And all the elements are rearranged in the newly allocated memory. Check javas connection documentation for the same. I'm not being very specific abt any single collection but it's across them

Comment: suppose the hastable has capacity of 16 and there is one element which is stored in bucket no 1..now all the capapcity is over and i am adding a new element which has the same hascode() as that of bucket no 1. so logically it should get stored in bucket no 1. so will the hastable resize as i am adding a new element..or will it check first the hashcode and place it in bucket 1 and not resize the hashtable